# Sony Camera Remote Control Python ILCE-6400

Tags: python, sdk, camera, sony

This month I have been looking for a way to control my camera with a python script. I was trying with libraries, **but none of them worked**. I also tried Sony SDK, but sadly it isn't compatible with my camera **alpha-6400**.

I cannot find any sample scripts on the internet, or how the syntax works. Can somebody **share a sample script** for remotely controlling my camera, I need basic functions such as **focus, aperture, ISO and live feed.**

**Thanks!**

Comment: Were you ever to find a solution?